# Nav bar and logo in banner (slider)

Tags: css, html

I'm a beginner and I would like to ask you: How do I make the nav bar and logo in the banner (slider) picture like [this page](http://themeforest.net/item/kubb-photography-magazine-html5-template/full_screen_preview/8132343).

This is what I have:

```css
body,
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 96%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 2%;
}
header {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 10px 0;
}
header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-indent: -10000px;
  background: url(images/logo.png) no-repeat;
  width: 105px;
  float: left;
}
header nav {
  float: right;
}
header:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}
header nav h2 {
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-indent: -10000px;
}
header nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 42px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
header nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
header nav li a.current {
  color: #28b8d8;
}
#main-banner img {
  width: 100%;
}
#main-banner {
  max-height: 700px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1 class="logo">kubb</h1>
    <nav>
      <h2>Main Navigation</h2>
      <div id="burger-nav"></div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Journal</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

</header>
<div id="main-banner">
  <img src="images/banner.png" alt="banner">
</div>


<main class="wrapper">
  <div id="hello">
    <p>
      <h2>Hello! I'm Jonathon Kubb, a freenalnce Photographer.</h2>
      Based in New York, I specialize in landscape, advertorial and conceptual photography.</p>
  </div>

  <section id="services">
    <h2>What services do i offer</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="images/image_1.png" alt="Landscape">
        <h3>Landscape</h3>
        <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Duis mollis inceptos mollisest commodo luctus erat.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this  :

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.slideshow = function(options) {
    options = $.extend({
      'timeout': 3000,
      'speed': 400 // 'normal'
    }, options);
    // We loop through the selected elements, in case the slideshow was called on more than one element e.g. `$('.foo, .bar').slideShow();`
    return this.each(function() {
      // Inside the setInterval() block, `this` references the window object instead of the slideshow container element, so we store it inside a var
      var $elem = $(this);
      $elem.children().eq(0).appendTo($elem).show();
      // Iterate through the slides
      setInterval(function() {
        $elem.children().eq(0)
          // Hide the current slide and append it to the end of the image stack
          .hide().appendTo($elem) // As of jQuery 1.3.2, .appendTo() returns the inserted element
          // Fade in the next slide
          .fadeIn(options.speed)
      }, options.timeout);
    });
  };
}(jQuery));

// Name the slider

$(function() {
  $('.slider').slideshow({
    timeout: 7000,
    speed: 1000
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.slider li {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
}
.slider li .slide {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.slider li .slide figcaption {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  margin-top: 50vh;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <section>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <span><img src="https://logomarts.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/logo-example2.jpg" alt="logo" width="50px;" />Project name</span></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>


    <ul class="slider">
      <li>
        <figure class="slide" style="background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/260511/1d9326c2ae66befef4e39c3426adf17a.jpg)">
          <figcaption>hello</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure class="slide" style="background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/260511/______by_Thoum.jpg)">
          <figcaption>yeah</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </li>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <p>Text Here</p>
  <div>
    <p>Some more text..</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I only wanted to know, how I add the navigation and logo in banner (in same div). Same like this page: http://themeforest.net/item/kubb-photography-magazine-html5-template/full_screen_preview/8132343 ///This is my result what I made...but it's wrong http://prntscr.com/b1cpn0

Comment: You want a nav bar with the logo, name, home, about us, etc right? I think the above code has that. I have added a dark background to it.

Comment: Yes I want nav bar with logo in to the banner with opacity...can you tell me how can I do that? Need explain from my code what I send here...

Comment: Add the css to your code, you have put up only the html.

Comment: You may use the [bootstrap framework](http://getbootstrap.com/) and use the required classes (as shown in the example above) to get the same effect.

Comment: This is my CSS http://prntscr.com/b1cyy2 but still don't know how to add the navigation and logo section with opacity in the banner....I would be glad if you explained it to me on my code

Comment: Add it in the question.

Comment: body, ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;       
}

.wrapper {
    width: 96%;
    max-width: 1200px;    
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 2%;
}


header { 
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 10px 0;
}

Comment: header h1 {
    margin: 0;
    text-indent: -10000px;
    background: url(images/logo.png) no-repeat;
    width: 105px;
    float: left;    
}


header nav {
    float: right;
    
}

header:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    
}

Comment: header nav h2 {
    line-height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-indent: -10000px;
}

header nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 42px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

header nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}

header nav li a.current {
    color: #28b8d8;
    
}

#main-banner img{
    width: 100%;
}

#main-banner {
    max-height: 700px;
    overflow: hidden;

Comment: Ok. You want the logo before the home button?

Comment: You still dont understand me. I want logo and navigation into the banner with opacity. This is my result of code http://prnt.sc/b1cpn0 but I need this: http://prntscr.com/b1d3oa logo and navigation into the banner

Comment: can you explain to me?

Comment: Check my code. Use the same. For a transparent `navbar` just remove the "navbar-inverse" class from `nav` tag.

Comment: Yes. But I need solve this issue with my code. So can you tell me what I must fix?

Comment: I can't debug your code. You shall try to use my code to achieve whatever your want because the structure of what you want is given in my solution.